# ¿Cuál es la expresión regular que mejor se puede aplicar a un array como este [0] => [2 - 8)?

Tags: php, array

Tengo un arreglo en php del cuál obtengo valores de la siguiente forma

[0] => [2 - 8)

Resulta que necesito hacer una expresión que me reconozca esta forma, más que todo en la parte final  8)

Comment: Es decir lo que necesitas es obtener el 8 en este patrón?

Comment: No precisamente el 8 es el paréntesis pero si se puede con el 8 incluido mucho mejor.

Comment: Olvidaba ese 8 puede ser un entero o un float del tamaño que el usuario ingrese

Answer (score 1):

Hola si lo que necesitas es identificar en pleno la expresión y además hacer enfasis en el numero que mencionas (8), te puede convenir esta expresión:

```
\[\d{0,}\s-\s(\d{1,}\.\d{1,})\)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo notas la expresion se reconoce y reconoce el numero que estaria en lugar del 8, sin importar cuantos digitos tenga, pero debe existir el numero

Lo edité para ajustar a tu float number

Comment: Perfecto es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Eres el mejor!!!

Comment: Sí la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como correcta.